# Customize Calendar Winrt Xaml Toolkit

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm developing an Universal App for Win8.1, i've added the Winrt Xaml Toolkit dll but when i use Calendar control the strings of months appear only in English.
Is there any way to change them? I'm going crazy :D

PS: I've downloaded the source code of dll but there is no track of these strings

Comment: I have no experience with this, but I thought "Universal App" is for Windows 10 only, and Windows 8/8.1 Apps are no longer supported?

Comment: The term "Universal Apps" was first introduced when Windows 8.1 and WP 8.1 came out, because you were able to have a shared code base for the desktop and the phone, just like the the "Windows Universal Apps"  with Win10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [DateTimeHelper](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Calendar/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Calendar.Shared/Controls/Calendar/DateTimeHelper.cs) class, you can see the method `GetCurrentDateFormat` which uses the *en-US* format. This method is used in many places for the `Calendar` and `CalendarItem` controls from the toolkit.

You can try to import the project from the site instead of using the *NuGet package* and then change this method to use your device locale. You can maybe change it to something like this:

```
public static DateTimeFormatInfo GetCurrentDateFormat()
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
}
```

I haven't tested this code so this is just a hint where you should look for your solution.

Comment: i've tried to import project instead of NuGet package, so i've generated my .dll's (Toolkit and Calendar) from source code and added to my project. But when i'm using the Calendar Control, it generate a StackOverflow exception in GetPatternCore method from CalendarAutomationPeer.

Comment: My mistake, i've added dll from "obj" folder and not from "bin". Thanks very much! I think this is a little important bug for this good library!

Comment: I've seen reports of it before and now started looking into fixing it.

Comment: Hi Filip, i've tried to contact you with mail about a week ago...like Kristian suggests i've replaced in DateTimeHelper en-US format with CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar